# SELECT INTO with LIMIT

Tags: mysql

If I have a table defined like so: `mytable(model char(4), price int);` and I'm trying to find the value closest to price given a base price, how would I go about it?

What I have is this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION findClosestPrice (value int) returns int
BEGIN
    DECLARE closestPrice int default -1;
    DECLARE row int default 0;
    DECLARE rows int default 0;
    DECLARE currPrice int default -1;
    select count(*) from mytable into rows;
    SET row=0;
    WHILE row < rows DO
        select price from mytable limit row, 1 into currPrice; <----- this gives an error
        SET row = row + 1;
    END WHILE;
END//
```

Why is it that I can't have that line?
How do I go about selecting the price from a current row in a loop and saving it into a variable that I've declared? I thought this would work but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the closest price to a base price with a single query:

```
SELECT model,price,(ABS(price-basePrice)) AS price_diff FROM mytable ORDER BY price_diff LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`into` must follow the column names before `from`.

**Change**:

```
select price from mytable limit row, 1 into currPrice;
```

**To**:

```
select price into currPrice from mytable limit row, 1;
```

**Refer to**:

> [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)
>   ... the INTO clause can appear either as shown in
>   the syntax description or immediately following the *select_expr* list
>   ...

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row, 1;`

Comment: Read the reference I posted for `limit` clause constraints. It says, you can only pass *constants* as limit range values when directly executing a select statement. When using a variable, you *must use prepared statement*.

Comment: There are various other errors in your *function* definition. Example: no `return` statement. You need to correct such errors.